# I am trying to get hyperlinks printed onto the excel sheet under the class "search-results". What needs to be changed in the VBA elements?

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer, hyperlink

Edit: Thank your DearDeer for the solution

```
'GRV website copy and collect hyperlink
Sub Get_HyperLink1()

Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim http As New XMLHTTP60, html As New HTMLDocument
Dim nodeRaceResultsTable As HTMLHtmlElement
Dim nodeTr As HTMLHtmlElement
Dim nodeDiv As HTMLHtmlElement
Dim Element1 As HTMLHtmlElement
Dim node1 As HTMLHtmlElement
Dim currentUrl As String

With ie
    ie.Visible = True
```

The website below is where I want the VBA to navigate

```
ie.Navigate "https://fasttrack.grv.org.au/Meeting/Search?MeetingDateFrom=22%2F04%2F2020&MeetingDateTo=22%2F04%2F2020&Status=&TimeSlot=&DayOfWeek=&DisplayAdvertisedEvents=false&AllTracks=True&SelectedTracks=AllTracks&searchbutton=Search"
    Do Until .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
End With
```

I'm trying to get the hyperlinks with the VBA elements below

```
For Each nodeRaceResultsTable In html.getElementsByClassName("search-results")
For Each nodeTr In nodeRaceResultsTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
    With nodeTr.getElementsByTagName("td")
```

The part below is where I want this VBA to grab the hyperlink and print it on the excel sheet

```
    ws.Cells(5, 5) = .Item(1).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).href
    End With
Next
Next

    ie.Quit
    Set ie = Nothing
    Application.StatusBar = ""
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm assuming your code works but is putting the link in as plain text? If so, you can use the `=HYPERLINK()` formula.

Comment: I test DearDeer's code, and it works well. It can grab the hyperlinks and paste them into the sheet. I suggest that you can mark the answer as accepted. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
'GRV website copy and collect hyperlink
Sub Get_HyperLink1()

    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://fasttrack.grv.org.au/Meeting/Search?MeetingDateFrom=22%2F04%2F2020&MeetingDateTo=22%2F04%2F2020&Status=&TimeSlot=&DayOfWeek=&DisplayAdvertisedEvents=false&AllTracks=True&SelectedTracks=AllTracks&searchbutton=Search"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Dim aTag As Object, i As Long
        Set aTag = IE.document.querySelectorAll(".search-results [href]")
        
        For i = 0 To aTag.Length - 1
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 1) = aTag.Item(i)
        Next i
        
        IE.Quit
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `aTag.Item(i).href`